# <ng-select > after on changes formGroup control value still null,if searchTerm provided programmatically

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-ngselect

I have requirement to set searchTerm value Programmatically(using Virtual keypad) and search the dropdown should show searchterm based options.

where form control is updateOn:'blur'.

But here i am facing issue like form control is not getting updated after selecting dropdown option based on searchTerm provided by virtual input key(in example [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ng-select-example-formcontrol-not-updating?file=app/app.component.ts) red color text control value is null).

Steps:

1.press virtual key pad button

2.select any option

3.now check red color text value:

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It **is** getting updated, but you are using before it is updated. Even if you open the `<ng-select>` yourself, it will show different values in black and red.

If you **can**, I'd suggest for you to use `change.id` instead:

```js
    this.afterChangesFormControlValue = change.id;
```

But if you can't... if you wrap it inside a `setTimeout()`, even with a `0` delay, it will start working, since the setTimeout will be triggered only after the update is done:

```js
  setTimeout(() => {
    console.log('on select option after given search term from virtual keyboar')
    console.log("change:",change)
    console.log("form control value:",this.form.controls.example.value)
    this.afterChangesFormControlValue=this.form.controls.example.value;
  }, 0);
```

Both should produce the same results - they did when I tested in your Stackblitz, but `setTimeout` is a bit unsightly.

Comment: Thanks @gyohza for reply.As there i created sample and it's working with settimeout but real application it's seem like not working but after click/touch field control value get updating....so is there any other way like making ng-select dropdown programmatically touch(same like field click).

Comment: I won't be able to look into it for a few days (much homework from college), but I'll try to manage and come back to break it down more thoroughly. Isn't there anything different from your application in your example? Is there a reason why you can't use `change.id` inside your function? Maybe you could take a look at [ChangeDetectionStrategy](https://netbasal.com/a-comprehensive-guide-to-angular-onpush-change-detection-strategy-5bac493074a4) and changing it to see if it makes a difference.

Comment: Isn't there anything different ... example?-little bit yes but scenario is same in example just printing value but in real application field validation is based on control value ,...change.id i can't use... it's there in control _pendingValue.And i m using valuechanges on formControl.it's trigger two time changes one for pendingValue and one for manually set change.id.And if i keep emitEvent of control false at the time of setting value change.id  then valueChanges triggering after outside click of control.if i not setting then validation error.